# How do you specify the vertical distance between node chains when using the graphs library with the [grow right sep] option?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I'd like to use the `graphs` library to draw a block diagram, which is working fine so far.
However, I'd like add another input to the block diagram below by adding another node chain.
As you can see in the minimal working example below, the placeholder node chains `1 -> 2 -> 3;` and `a -> b -> c;` should be lower, but I cannot find any option to increase the vertical distance between node chains in `pgfmanual.pdf`.
Does anyone know of an option to specify the vertical distance between node chains in graphs when using the `grow right sep` option?

[image: minimal working example]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
    ,sum/.style={
        ,draw
        ,circle
        ,inner sep=0pt
        ,minimum size=2mm
        ,graphs/empty nodes
    }
    ,point/.style={
        ,draw
        ,circle,
        ,inner sep=0pt
        ,minimum size=1mm
        ,fill=black
        ,graphs/empty nodes
    }
    ,block/.style={
        ,draw
        ,rectangle          % shape
        ,minimum size = 6mm % size
        ,semithick         % border
    }
    ,mblock/.style={ % block with \displaystyle
        ,block
        ,font=\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\displaystyle}
    }
    ,mblockfeedback/.style 2 args={to path={
            node[mblock] (b) at ($(\tikztostart)!0.5!(\tikztotarget)+(0,#1)$){#2}
            -- ++(0,#1)
            -- (b)
            -- (b -| \tikztotarget)
            -- (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes
        }
    }
    ,minus/.style = {edge node={node[#1]{$-$}}}
    ,mblock/.append style={text height=3.25ex, text depth=2ex}
]
    \graph[grow right sep=1cm] {
            "$X(s)$"
            -> s1[sum]
            -> "$K$"[mblock]
            -> "$\frac{1}{s}$"[mblock]
            -- p1[point]
            -> "$Y(s)$";
            
            p1 ->[mblockfeedback={-1.5cm}{$\frac{1}{K}$},minus={pos=0.9,right}] s1;

            1 -> 2 -> 3;
            
            a -> b -> c;
        }
    ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `branch down`.

```tex
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,calc}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        ,sum/.style={
            ,draw
            ,circle
            ,inner sep=0pt
            ,minimum size=2mm
            ,graphs/empty nodes
        }
        ,point/.style={
            ,draw
            ,circle,
            ,inner sep=0pt
            ,minimum size=1mm
            ,fill=black
            ,graphs/empty nodes
        }
        ,block/.style={
            ,draw
            ,rectangle          % shape
            ,minimum size = 6mm % size
            ,semithick         % border
        }
        ,mblock/.style={ % block with \displaystyle
            ,block
            ,font=\everymath\expandafter{\the\everymath\displaystyle}
        }
        ,mblockfeedback/.style 2 args={to path={
                node[mblock] (b) at ($(\tikztostart)!0.5!(\tikztotarget)+(0,#1)$){#2}
                -- ++(0,#1)
                -- (b)
                -- (b -| \tikztotarget)
                -- (\tikztotarget)\tikztonodes
            }
        }
        ,minus/.style = {edge node={node[#1]{$-$}}}
        ,mblock/.append style={text height=3.25ex, text depth=2ex}
        ]
        \graph[grow right sep=1cm, branch down=3cm] {
            "$X(s)$"
            -> s1[sum]
            -> "$K$"[mblock]
            -> "$\frac{1}{s}$"[mblock]
            -- p1[point]
            -> "$Y(s)$";
            
            p1 ->[mblockfeedback={-1.5cm}{$\frac{1}{K}$},minus={pos=0.9,right}] s1;
            
            1 -> 2 -> 3;
            
            a -> b -> c;
        }
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is the answer to my question.If chain groups (something like ```a -> { b, c } -> d```) are not used, an alternative may be to start a new "invisible" node chain with ```/;``` to increase the logical depth counter by one so that the subsequent node chain is positioned below this empty node chain.
(A node in a graph may be specified as ```node name/node text```.
Not specifying a node name before the slash creates anonymous node, and not specifying the node text leads to an empty node.)